# How can you deserialize JSON data in C# (using DataContractJsonSerializer) without knowing all property names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I have been using the DataContractJsonSerializer to convert data returned from the HubSpot API into strongly-typed objects, but I'm having some trouble with the user profile object.

In this example, I am able to get the Id and IsContact properties, but can't figure out how to get the list of properties since I don't know in advance what those can be. I would like to make Properties a Dictionary but I'm not sure how to do this. I don't care about the versions for each property, just the value.

This is a simplified example of the data that is returned by the API:

```
{
  "vid": 72361,
  "is-contact": true,
  "properties": {
    "city": {
      "value": "Burlington",
      "versions": [
        {
          "value": "Burlington",
          "source-type": "SALESFORCE",
          "source-id": "continuous",
          "source-label": null,
          "timestamp": 1384319976006,
          "selected": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "country": {
      "value": "US",
      "versions": [
        {
          "value": "US",
          "source-type": "SALESFORCE",
          "source-id": "continuous",
          "source-label": null,
          "timestamp": 1384319976006,
          "selected": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "company": {
      "value": "Bridgeline Digital",
      "versions": [
        {
          "value": "Bridgeline Digital",
          "source-type": "SALESFORCE",
          "source-id": "continuous",
          "source-label": null,
          "timestamp": 1384319976006,
          "selected": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the object I am trying to deserialize to:

```
[DataContract]
public class HubSpotUserProfile
{
    [DataMember(Name = "vid")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "is-contact")]
    public bool IsContact { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "redirect")]
    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "properties")]
    public Dictionary<string, HubSpotUserProfileProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class HubSpotUserProfileProperty
{
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I call this method to perform the deserialization:

```
    public static T Post<T>(string url, string postData) where T : class
    {
        string json = Post(url, postData);

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

                return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

When I do this, no error is thrown, but Properties always has a Count of 0. Any idea on how I can accomplish this goal?

Comment: What would you do with the extra properties? Since you don't know what they are, it may be difficult to write code to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonObject type for your Properties property. In some very strange case DataContractJsonSerializer doesn't support Dictionary<> type in this case

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'm using .NET 4.0 which does not have JsonObject. Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: You may start using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json). This lib doesn't have any problems with dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

If JSON.NET is an option then James has recently added ExtensionData support. See http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data.

```
public class DirectoryAccount
{
  // normal deserialization
  public string DisplayName { get; set; }

  // these properties are set in OnDeserialized
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string Domain { get; set; }

  [JsonExtensionData]
  private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;

  [OnDeserialized]
  private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
  {
    // SAMAccountName is not deserialized to any property
    // and so it is added to the extension data dictionary
    string samAccountName = (string)_additionalData["SAMAccountName"];

    Domain = samAccountName.Split('\\')[0];
    UserName = samAccountName.Split('\\')[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is most useful when you have some known properties next to unknown properties on the same object. In your case since all the unknown properties are on a child property, it's probably easiest to declare a property of type JObject (from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq) called Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your chosen package for deserializing objects, your current models will work. We use [JSon.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) for this exact purpose with HubSpot.

Here's samples of what we use...

```
[DataContract]
public class ContactHubSpotModel {
// snip for brevity 
[DataMember(Name = "properties")]     
public Dictionary<string, ContactProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ContactProperty
{
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "versions")]
    List<ContactPropertyVersion> Versions { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ContactPropertyVersion
{
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "source-type")]
    public string SourceType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "source-id")]
    public string SourceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "source-label")]
    public string SourceLabel { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "timestamp")]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "selected")]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can dump a copy of your contact output into a file for validation like so...

```
string contactJson = GetContactString(); // pulls sample data stored in a .txt
ContactHubSpotModel contactModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactHubSpotModel>(contactJson);
```